# Как из терминала заменить слово в файлах в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Во всех файлах в папке и во вложенных папках.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Например, так:

```
grep -lr -e 'было' . | xargs sed -i 's/было/стало/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/было/стало/g' {} \;
```